# check validate forms with validationengine plugin in JavaScript

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I'm a starter with a jQuery validation plugin ([validationengine](http://www.position-absolute.com) ). I wrote this code

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="validationEngine.jquery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.validationEngine-fa.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            jQuery("#form1").validationEngine();
            $("#Button1").click(function () {

                alert("hhhhhhhhhhh");
            });
        });
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button2_Click" />
        <input id="Text1" type="text" class="validate[required] text-input" />
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I want when user click in Button1 first validate forms.  If form is valid alert in show but by this code when user click in the button1 alert is showing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#form1").validationEngine();

        $("#Button1").live('click', function () {
            var valid = $("#form1").validationEngine('validate');
            var vars = $("#form1").serialize();

            if (valid == true) {

                alert("Hi");

            } else {
                $("#form1").validationEngine();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

This also works

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#form1").validationEngine();

        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            var valid = $("#form1").validationEngine('validate');
            var vars = $("#form1").serialize();

            if (valid == true) {

                alert("Hi");

            } else {
                $("#form1").validationEngine();
            }
        });
    });
```