# Validate on button click using validationEngine bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I was doing [this](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine). and i was doing pretty ok with the tutorial i am doing the validation for form like this

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#formID2").validationEngine('attach', {
      onValidationComplete: function(form, status) {
        alert("The form status is: " + status + ", it will never submit");
      }
    })
  });
</script>
```

I am wondering how to make the validation using button click.. I want to remove the submit form and i want to put the validation on button click. Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#Button1").click(function () {
            var valid = $("#form1").validationEngine('validate');
            var vars = $("#form1").serialize();

            if (valid == true) {

                alert("Hi");

            } else {
                $("#form1").validationEngine();
            }
        });
```

Try this one i got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450409/check-validate-forms-with-validationengine-plugin-in-javascript) it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

When Button type is == Submit then use follwing code,

```
$("#FormId").validationEngine({
        onValidationComplete : function(form, status) {
            if (status) {
                 alert("Hi");                   
            }
            return false;
        },
        scroll : false,
    });
```